# DELETE query not working but there is no error

Tags: mysql, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to delete a row in my favorite table but it just doesn't work. I get no error messages and I am getting the correct values

```
removeFavorite(user_id: number, question_id: number, answer_id: number | null) {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
        'DELETE FROM favorites WHERE user_id=? AND question_id=? AND answer_id=?',
        [user_id, question_id, answer_id],
        (error, results: ResultSetHeader) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          console.log(user_id, question_id, answer_id);
          console.log(results);
          resolve(results.insertId);
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

I have checked that the query works while doing it directly at the mysql database so I am completely lost on what to do

Comment: If your WHERE returns no matches, there will be no errors and no deleted records

Comment: What do you mean by _"it just doesn't work"_? Do the expected records not get deleted? What debugging have you done? Have you checked the actual values you're passing to the function? FYI if `answer_id` is `null` you should use `AND answer_id IS NULL`

Comment: Why would there be an `insertId` for a `DELETE` query?

Comment: Thank you `DELETE FROM favorites WHERE user_id=? AND question_id=? AND (answer_id=? OR answer_id IS NULL)` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was trying to set answer_id=null which didn't register properly and therefore it didn't find the correct row to delete. Adding answer_id IS NULL to the query made it work correctly.

So all I needed to do was change my previous query to:

`DELETE FROM favorites WHERE user_id=? AND question_id=? AND (answer_id=? OR answer_id IS NULL)`